# How do you set a JavaScript onclick event to a class with css

Tags: javascript, css

Let's say I want that every time the user click any link an alert pops up that says "hohoho". 
Do I need to add `onclick="alert('hohoho')"` to every link or can I set this with CSS so that it works with every link?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

You can't do it with just CSS, but you can do it with Javascript, and (optionally) [jQuery](http://jquery.com).

If you want to do it without jQuery:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
        for(var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
            var anchor = anchors[i];
            anchor.onclick = function() {
                alert('ho ho ho');
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

And to do it without jQuery, and only on a specific class (ex: `hohoho`):

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
        for(var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
            var anchor = anchors[i];
            if(/\bhohoho\b/).match(anchor.className)) {
                anchor.onclick = function() {
                    alert('ho ho ho');
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

If you are okay with using [jQuery](http://jquery.com), then you can do this for all anchors:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('a').click(function() {
            alert('ho ho ho');
        });
    });
</script>
```

And this jQuery snippet to only apply it to anchors with a specific class:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('a.hohoho').click(function() {
            alert('ho ho ho');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Or you could use `document.getElementsByClassName("class")`

Comment: Incredible, so it can indeed actually be done without a library! I found an excellent article about JS events as well.. http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/domevents

Comment: @JCOC611: I didn't use `getElementsByClassName` because it doesn't work on every major browser.

Comment: @luminarious: Yay, everything can be done without a library! @Alex: :O I didn't know, I don't use it anyways lol...you mean IE, right?

Comment: 2020 here, you can use `getElementsByClassName` on all browsers safely: https://caniuse.com/getelementsbyclassname

Comment: This probably doesn't work when a tag of this name/class is created and added to the document *after* loading the page, whereas CSS would still apply.

Answer (score 45):

You can do this by thinking of it a little bit differently. Detect when the body is clicked (`document.body.onclick` - i.e. anything on the page) and then check if the element clicked (`event.srcElement` / `e.target`) has a class and that that class name is the one you want:

```
document.body.onclick = function(e) {   //when the document body is clicked
    if (window.event) {
        e = event.srcElement;           //assign the element clicked to e (IE 6-8)
    }
    else {
        e = e.target;                   //assign the element clicked to e
    }

    if (e.className && e.className.indexOf('someclass') != -1) {
        //if the element has a class name, and that is 'someclass' then...
        alert('hohoho');
    }
}
```

Or a more concise version of the above:

```
document.body.onclick= function(e){
   e=window.event? event.srcElement: e.target;
   if(e.className && e.className.indexOf('someclass')!=-1)alert('hohoho');
}
```

Comment: I had issues with `document.body.onclick`, but it seems to work well with `document.onclick`.

Answer (score 10):

You could do it with jQuery.

```
$('.myClass').click(function() {
  alert('hohoho');
});
```

Comment: Is it possible with just css and javascript though?

Comment: jQuery is a javascript library, so it already is just HTML/CSS/JS

Comment: Yes, but you'd have to write your own JavaScript code to iterate the elements in the DOM and query their attributes to see if a css class is applied to them and then take action. For example: http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/domcss but in my opinion the amount of code you'll have to write to be safe about it is not worth it compared to using a community-backed, free project.

Comment: @jsoldi I'm not a mind-reader, and your comment didn't give me any confidence in your knowledge of HTML/CSS/JS.

Answer (score 4):

It can't be done via CSS as CSS only changes the presentation (e.g. only Javascript can make  the alert popup). I'd strongly recommend you check out a Javascript library called [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) as it makes doing something like this trivial:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a").click(function(){
    alert("hohoho");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Following JCOC611 suggestion:

```
window.onload = function() {    
    let elements = document.getElementsByClassName("someClassName");

    for(let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].onclick = function () {
            alert("Clicked in an element of the class.");
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution through CSS, It does not use any JavaScript at all

HTML:

```
<a href="#openModal">Open Modal</a>

<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
        <div>   <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>

                <h2>Modal Box</h2>

            <p>This is a sample modal box that can be created using the powers of CSS3.</p>
            <p>You could do a lot of things here like have a pop-up ad that shows when your website loads, or create a login/register form for users.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.modalDialog {
    position: fixed;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    z-index: 99999;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.modalDialog:target {
    opacity:1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
.modalDialog > div {
    width: 400px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10% auto;
    padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
}
.close {
    background: #606061;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -12px;
    text-align: center;
    top: -10px;
    width: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}
.close:hover {
    background: #00d9ff;
}
```

[CSS alert No JavaScript Just pure HTML and CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/a2t3a079/)

I believe that it will do the trick for you as it has for me

Answer (score 2):

Many 3rd party JavaScript libraries allow you to select all elements that have a CSS class of a particular name applied to them. Then you can iterate those elements and dynamically attach the handler.

There is no CSS-specific manner to do this.

In [JQuery](http://jquery.com/), you can do:

```
$(".myCssClass").click(function() { alert("hohoho"); });
```

Answer (score 2):

Asking about "a class" in the question title, the answer is `getElementsByClassName`:

```
  var hrefs = document.getElementsByClassName("YOUR-CLASS-NAME-HERE");
  for (var i = 0; i < hrefs.length; i++) {
   hrefs.item(i).addEventListener('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); /*use if you want to prevent the original link following action*/
    alert('hohoho');
   });
  }
```