# how to show alert on button click ussing css

Tags: jquery, css

is there any way to show alert using css on button click.?

can we do using css?As we do the same thing using jquery .

```
$( ".btn" ).click(function() {
  alert("hiii")
});
```

Comment: No, you can't trigger the alert modal using CSS

Comment: is `btn` the class assigned to the tagret element

Comment: one more thing can we check landscape and portrait media querry on desktop

Comment: @media screen and (orientation:landscape)
{
   body
   {
      background: red;
   }
}

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is a way to do this.  At the core your question is "can I launch javascript from a css click event".  I think the jquery you displayed is the best way to do this.  Also see this link:  [How do you set a JavaScript onclick event to a class with css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588759/how-do-you-set-a-javascript-onclick-event-to-a-class-with-css)

Comment: @media screen and (orientation:landscape)
{
   body
   {
      background: red;
   }
}

Answer (score 0):

You can't open the standard alert window, but you can get creative and show a custom dialog using the `:focus` selector and `:after` pseudo-element. Here's something I whipped up: http://jsfiddle.net/baY97/