# Link-type buttons on bot framework

Tags: botframework

I've been building a solution on Bot Framework V3 using Direct Line where I'd like to have links instead of buttons in my bot.
The 'link-type' button should repeat the text within the link and pass it along to the bot conversation in order to be processed.
Something like available on the MS technical support chatbot (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/contact/virtual-agent/?flowId=smc-home-hero&referrer=www.bing.com&partnerId=smc).
In practice, if one types something like 'I'd like to create an account', the bot offers links that can be clicked and then instead of sending the user to an external site it remains in the bot sending the clicked text for processing.
Thought I could use markdown to achieve that but it didn't work.
Suggestions are welcome.

Thanks in advance
[image]

Comment: Can you post the code you used to try to make these links?

Comment: Thanks. Code snippet as follows: protected override async Task RespondFromQnAMakerResultAsync(IDialogContext context, IMessageActivity message, QnAMakerResults result)
        {
            Answer = result.Answers.First().Answer;
            await context.PostAsync(Answer);
          }
The answer + suggested questions comes from QnaMaker as in the screen shot https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnpERZZbH7htqu9mBf96v0wumA5NoA

Answer (score 0):

> using Direct Line where I'd like to have links instead of buttons in my bot

Such function should be implemented in your channel.

1. In the web it could be achieved via js
2. In other channels it has to be built-in (like slash command in the telegram https://core.telegram.org/botshttps://core.telegram.org/bots commands section )

You can handle such messages in your main dialog flow or use scorable https://blog.botframework.com/2017/07/06/scorables/

Comment: Thanks RondoK. Since I'm using Direct Line on a web page I guess a js solution should be the best approach in this case . Any suggestion where I could find a code sample for that? Just to make sure we're in-sync this is the expected outcome 1drv.ms/u/s!AnpERZZbH7htqu9mBf96v0wumA5NoA

Comment: @Amintas Lopes Neto . I diddn't saw any code samples for such situation, but you can use code from MS technical support chatbot 
OR
implement yourself using <button class="suggestion"> Command </button> for render as button(use css for more style https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/contact/virtual-agent/?flowId=smc-home-hero&referrer=www.bing.com&partnerId=smc) 
track 'on click' action with class name "suggestion" via js or jquery 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588759/how-do-you-set-a-javascript-onclick-event-to-a-class-with-css

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint! Let me try that out. Cheers