# How do I apply the same .onclick function to multiple elements?

Tags: javascript, html

I have 5 divs which each need to perform the same function:

-collapse all divs
-expand parent div

each element shares a class.

When I use getElementsByClass it returns a
list of 5 items.

I try to use a for loop on the list but that doesn't work.

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"> x <div>
<div>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"> x <div>
<div>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"> x <div>
<div>
```

JS:

```
var child = getElementsByClassName("child");
var parent = getElementsByClassName("parent");
var i;
for(i=0; i<child.length; i++){
    i.onClick = function(){
        parent.style.height = "0";
        i.parentElement.style.height = "100px;
};
```

Comment: @NageshSanika — They've got a closure … that's the cause of the problem.

Comment: besides that your code is full of errors (HTML and JS!), i is just the incrementer of your for-loop, not a DOM node, try: 

    `var children = document.getElementsByClassName('child');

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(children, el => {
        el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            e.currentTarget.parentElement.style.height = "100px";
        });
    });`

Comment: apart from the closure issue, `parent` is also an array. so ` parent.style.height = "0"` will not work. loop through the parent to set its height 0

Comment: found it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588759/how-do-you-set-a-javascript-onclick-event-to-a-class-with-css